# Unable to call Box API through Postman, even with a seemingly valid access token

Tags: javascript, rest, http, oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm trying to make an API call to Box using Postman, but I get a 401 Unauthorized Access error even though the token is valid. I got the token using OAuth2 Token generator:

```
{
  "access_token": "lbPtcZ0YVALIDTOKENiTp8yXZ",
  "expires_in": 3790,
  "restricted_to": [],
  "refresh_token": "7d0eLGF3cA2uKv9GlhigBMKCo4bQREFRESHTOKENSBdNkNQtAms5K56A9",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Here's my Postman instance:
[image: Postman Instance]

Am I not entering my parameters correctly in Postman?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also no GET endpoint for folders without an ID

https://api.box.com/folders

Try

https://api.box.com/folders/0

Comment: Hmm, you're right this was it. Works now.  But in Box's API docs, they have listed /folders under Resources so I assumed that was a valid endpoint. Any idea where can I find the actual endpoints?

Comment: /folders is a valid endpoint if you are doing a POST (to create a new folder), but for GET, PUT, and DELETE you have to include an ID.  Same goes for many of the other endpoints (like /comments)

Answer (score 1):

You've set up the Authorization header correctly, but you'll want to remove the double quotes from your token.

```
Authorization: Bearer lbPtcZ0YVALIDTOKENiTp8yXZ
```

Comment: Thanks, this did help along with Peter's answer.